# Pass Parameters to swagger.json endpoint

Tags: java, json, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

We use Swagger to generate our API specification on our Java backend. The maven dependency used is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

We are looking to be able to pass some parameters to the /swagger.json endpoint, likely query parameters, that will modify the swagger.json that is generated and returned. The motivation for this is that we generate a few different API's all from the same server, and would like to be able to simply hit the /swagger.json endpoint with a query param specifying the API to generate the correct JSON, e.g. removing certain endpoints or changing certain authorizations, depending on the input.

I've stumbled onto the [ReaderListener interface](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/1.5.16/io/swagger/jaxrs/config/ReaderListener.html) that would allow us to make the mods to the JSON; however, we need to be able to pass some input to this from the the cURL, e.g.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/swagger.json?key=value'
```

And get that <key,value> into the ReaderListener code, as an example possible solution.